# $x=2\sin A/(1+\cos A+\sin A)$ , then $ (1-\cos A- \sin A)/\cos A=$?

Tags: trigonometry

$x=\cfrac{2\sin A}{1+\cos A+\sin A}$ , then $ \cfrac{1-\cos A- \sin A}{\cos A}=?$

Options are

$1$. $x$

$2$. $\cfrac 1x$

$3$. $-x$

$4$. $\cfrac{-1}x$

Can not attend it.

I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: maybe you can try the different options and see the one who leads to tautologic (obvious) equality ? (If you really don't have another idea)

Comment: Try https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

Comment: laliga (account number ?) This site is not a homework completion service, despite, like we see  below, there are users so desperate for rep, that they'll answer anything.  You posted what  isn't even a question.  It is a transcription of a problem assigned to you, for you to do.  You failed to even attempt it.  If you "don't know how to approach it", it's time to read your text and lecture notes which cover the material you failed to read, or attend to.  Don't come here and hand us your homework.  You are welcome to post here if and only if you're willing to help us help you.

Comment: this is not my homework and i am in class 6

Answer (score 2):

Let $$ y ={\cos A \over 1-\cos A- \sin A}$$ We are interested in ${1\over y}$. Then $$xy = {2\sin A\cos A \over 1-(\cos A+\sin A)^2 } ={\sin 2A \over 1-\cos ^2A -\sin^2 A -2\sin A \cos A } =- 1$$

So ${1\over y}  = -x$

Answer (score 0):

$x=\dfrac{2sinA}{1+cosA+sinA}.\left(\dfrac{1-cosA-sinA}{1-cosA-sinA}\right)$

$x=\dfrac{{2sinA}.({1-cosA-sinA})}{1-(cosA+SinA)^{2}}=-\dfrac{({1-cosA-sinA})}{cosA}$

$\implies\dfrac{({1-cosA-sinA})}{cosA}=-x$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\cos A+\sin A+1)(\cos A+\sin A-1)=\cdots=2\sin A\cos A$$